# Firebase authentication error codes // Angular - Ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to translate error throwbacks for my Ionic application which are returned from Firebase authentication.

**For example:** When user write an e-mail into login form(which is wrong e-mail) firebase going to check authentication table and throwback

**"There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. 
The user may have been deleted."**

That's the point what i am working for.

```
this.auth.signInWithEmail(credentials)
.then(
    () => this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage),
    error => this.loginError = error.message);

// Now error text in loginError variable 
if(this.loginError=== 
    "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.")
{
    loginError="Something else in my language"; // change to text
}
```

I know it a bit hard-coded but i did not found any solution about it.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `if` statement is checking `this.loginError` before the error response comes from the server. Browser XHRs are non-blocking. That means that the JavaScript engine does not wait for a response from the server before executing subsequent code. The code blocks in the `.then` method are stored as a reference and only executed when a response becomes available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This reply solved to my problem. Regards.